# How to plot multiple values using geoChart in GoogleVIS R

Tags: r, googlevis

Say we have a sample table for Medical Devices

```
Country Implanted Explanted
USA      100        20
Great Britain      30          5
Canada    50       10
Netherlands  80    30
Germany      90     20
Japan       60      10
India      50       20
China       60       20
```

let's say I want to plot these countries using GeoCharts or GeoMap, where a user hovers over the country and gets the values for BOTH Implanted and Explanted.

Is it possible to display multiple attributes (Implanted, Explanted) per country on a SINGLE Google Map using GeoChart or GeoMap

I have had success with only either Implanted/Explanted

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and show what have you tried so far.

Comment: my_df <- read.csv(file.choose(),header = T)     # select a csv file containing above data

library(googleVis)  # self explanatory

mg <- gvisGeoChart(my_df,locationvar = "country",colorvar = "Implanted")    # create an object of type gvisGeoChart

plot(mg)   # plot the object   As you can see I want to plot both Implanted and Explanted for a given country on the same map using gvisGeoChart

Comment: Could you edit the code and post your code there instead of  comments?

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/mages/googleVis/issues/52) link it seems that it is not possible to add multiple attributes to the tooltip.